Change Nodemon script depending on the changed file(s)
Nodemon knows what files have changed when it restarts the compiling script. But how do I get that information into the script?
const nodemon= require('nodemon');

let inputDir = process.argv[2];
let outputDir = process.argv[3];

let script = `bash scripts/build.sh -i ${inputDir} -o ${outputDir}`;

nodemon({
    ext: 'js,ts',
    watch: inputDir,
    exec: script,
})
    .on("start", () => console.log("start"))
    .on("crash", () => console.log("script crashed"))
    .on("restart", (files) => {
        console.log(`restart due to ${files}`));
        let scriptWithUpdates = `bash scripts/build.sh -i ${inputDir} -o ${outputDir} -- ${files}`;
        // How do I run this instead of the normal script?
    }
    .on("exit", () => console.log("Exit cleanly"))

The reason I need to do this: nodemon tells my compiler to recompile all files currently, while only one needs to be recompiled.
